# Create a file in linux via php/shell script?

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

I am trying to create a php\shell script to create a file. I am using the exec() command to create the link between the shell and the php itself. I am also trying to receive data from the user and for that I have a php form page linked to the script.

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['txt_username'];
exec("sudo echo $username > file.txt");
?>
```

From my research I have found that exec() does not accept $_POST or $_GET variables. I have also tried functions like extract(), getenv() and var_dump(), as well as escapeshellcmd() and escapeshellarg(). Could someone help me?

Comment: `exec()` does not know where string variables originate from. You ought to escape them for shell context however, `escapeshellarg()` comes to mind. And `exec` is not uncommonly constrained by the server setup. Why aren't you using PHP-builtins for writing to files?

Comment: It's for a school project in which I have to create a php form page to receive data to input into a file information from the user. I can't use php builtins.

Comment: @user2229813: I think you misunderstood **mario**: php has functions for writing to files, such as `file_put_contents()`. Why exactly can't you use them?

Comment: Ouch, this looks evil. Do not do that! Let PHP write this file. You are passing client input directly to the OS' command line, which is more then a nasty security hole.

Comment: Imagine if the username as typed in the HTML form is exactly the `"foo; /bin/rm -rf /"` string -without the double quotes....

Answer (score 1):

is this what you are looking ?

```
<?php

$uname = $_POST['UserName']; 
$file_to_write = "file.txt";
$open_file = fopen($file_to_write,'w') or die ("Cant Open File");
fwrite($file_to_write, $uname);
flcose($file_to_write);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this.

```
<?php
    file_put_contents( 'file.txt', $_POST['txt_username'] );
?>
```